# Can CSS3 access the browsing context name?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML file that wants to be viewed standalone, so it needs an h1.
But I want to embed it in another page too, where it does not need an h1, using object.

What I've come up with is

```
<head>
<style>
#foo h1 {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
document.body.id = window.name;
</script>
<h1>title</h1>
Content.
</body>
```

The style has no effect when the document is loaded by itself, because the window.name is null. But, in the including file, I use:

```
<object data="that-file-up-there.html" name="foo">
```

which gives the nested browsing context the name foo, and then the javascript copies it as the id of the nested document , thus causing the style to trigger, and suppress the h1. This works, but am I overlooking a way to not need the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do this without javascript because HTML and CSS are not programming languages that can copy attributes, elements or properties from other pages.

Comment: My first hope was that something like  object h1 { display: none; } would work, but it didn't... the nested browsing context doesn't seem to admit that it is nested, in the sense of nested selectors. But I would hoping there was some technique that would allow such detection, without resorting to javascript. Alternate to   object h1, something like   window[name=foo] h1  would be a handy selector capability.